# Boundless Suite Geotools Documentation BUILD FAILURE

Tags: git, ant, build, geoserver, geotools

I'm trying to build the Boundless Suite (https://boundlessgeo.com):

https://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite

I've installed all required base software packages and the required additional packages.-

Following:

1. Cloned the repository:

   % git clone git://github.com/boundlessgeo/suite.git suite
    % cd suite
2. Initialized submodule dependencies:

   % git submodule update --init --recursive
3. Do a full build:

   % ant

I've removed Composer and Docs. But I still got fail to build:

```
     [exec] [INFO] GeoTools Documentation ............................ FAILURE [4.507s]
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [INFO] Total time: 5:51.778s
     [exec] [INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 04 10:19:26 ART 2017
     [exec] [INFO] Final Memory: 94M/225M
     [exec] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     [exec] [WARNING] The requested profile "ysld" could not be activated because it does not exist.
     [exec] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run (compile) on project docs: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
     [exec] [ERROR] /home/klaus/suite/geoserver/geotools/geotools/docs/build.xml:45: The following error occurred while executing this line:
     [exec] [ERROR] /home/klaus/suite/geoserver/geotools/geotools/docs/build.xml:76: exec returned: 1
     [exec] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
     [exec] [ERROR] 
     [exec] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
     [exec] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
     [exec] [ERROR] 
     [exec] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
     [exec] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
     [exec] [ERROR] 
     [exec] [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
     [exec] [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :docs

BUILD FAILED /home/klaus/suite/build.xml:15:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/klaus/suite/build.xml:17:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/klaus/suite/geoserver/build.xml:15:
The following error occurred while executing this line: 
/home/klaus/suite/geoserver/build.xml:17:
The following error occurred while executing this line: 
/home/klaus/suite/geoserver/geotools/build.xml:16:
The following error occurred while executing this line: 
/home/klaus/suite/build/common.xml:291: exec returned: 1
```

What's I'm doing wrong?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Boundless messed up the build flags somewhere.

The easiest way to get the [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) documentation is to download them from the [official site](http://docs.geotools.org/) or to build them from the a clone of the [GeoTools repository](https://github.com/geotools/geotools) and run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` and then go to the docs directory and run `mvn clean install -DskipTests` again. The docs will be in your `target` directory then.